# Effciently assign unused color to the element

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I want to implement a function that can efficiently find the color which hasn't been used yet.

Let's assume that I have 3 colors (e.g. 'red', 'green', 'blue) available. What the function does is that when users click on a button, the system will add an icon and assigned it with a color that hasn't been used. Users can change the color of icons or remove any icons at any given time. If all the colors have been used, then it will just assign the 'red' color.

I understand that if color can only be assigned once, the function can be efficiently done with the Stack structure, however since users are able to change the color of an icon, I could not think of a way to utilize the Stack structure. One of the situations that can happen is that the user adds the first icon and the icon got assigned to the color **red**, then the user adds the second icon but manually changed the icon color to **red**. So when the user tries to add the third icon, how do I find what color is available?

Currently, what I have is an Object/Dictionary with the key is the color and the value is an array that contains the icon the color has been assigned to. e.g. `{'red': [icon1, icon2], 'blue': [], 'green: []}`. Then, when users add icons, I will loop over the keys of the Object and check if the value array is empty. However, I feel this is computationally expensive because for each color I need to loop over the object and check its value.

I am implementing this function in JavaScript, however, I am looking for a general algorithm to solve this question.

Comment: You could maintain a heap of lists keyed by the length and color of each list. But if you only have three, then the straightforward structure will be more efficient.

Comment: What’s the issue with using an unordered map/dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

If there are only a few colors or buttons (say under 1000, whichever is fewer), it likely doesn't matter how efficient your algorithm is and simply collecting the values or buttons into a list and checking each list in turn to see if it has any values in it whenever you need another color is practical

This will be `O(n)` as the worst case iterates over the entire collection

If you are already collecting the buttons into a collection (which is likely for how you are displaying them), iterating over this collection to check some color member and stopping when you have every member of your color collection may be more efficient than keeping a separate list of colors used, but this will be language and implementation-dependent

Perhaps an efficient solution in this case would be to use a set and check its length

```
colors_total = set(colors)
colors_used  = set()

color = null

for button in buttons:
    colors_used.add(button.color)
    if len(colors_used) >= len(colors_total):
        color = red
        break

if not color:
    color = colors_total.set_subtract(colors_used)[index0]
```